# uGet Chromium integration not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, chromium, uget, chrome-extension

Chromium extension of uGet is not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are aware of the issue with the extension. This an issue created by Google when they chose to break the functionality of NPAPI.

We are working on a replacement extension to compensate for the changes. In the meantime, the clipboard monitor should suffice as a temporary replacement.

Comment: Is there any update...?

Comment: Yes, we are in the testing phase for the new extension so we are getting closer and closer.

Comment: We still waiting :)

Comment: Blame Google but it is almost done